# Eclipse: Project Explorer issue

Tags: eclipse, maven, explorer

I have following Maven project in my Eclipse:

[image]

Next to `dev-bundle` the `main` directory should normally contain two more directories:

- java
- resources

I deleted the project (without deleting the files on the local disk) from Eclipse and imported it again as Maven project -> no success.

This is how it looks on my local disk:

[image]

What's wrong with Eclipse?

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: The _Project Explorer_ is not a raw file system view, but a view adapted to developer needs: it shows additional things, certain things differently, and there are also things that are intentionally hidden. It can be customized via the view menu (the three dots at the top right) _Filters and Customization..._ In your case, the source folders `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` are shown compacted at the top. In contrast, `src/main/dev-bundle` is not a source folder. If it should also be a source folder, you have to fix that in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: There is no `Customization` if I click on `Filters`. Can you show me it with a screenshot? That could help me better. Thanks.

Comment: Then you in the _Package Explorer_, not in the _Project Explorer_. Both are similar, the _Package Explorer_ is more legacy and the _Project Explorer_ has a bit more options.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. For some reason I didn't realize that I opened the `Package Explorer`, not the `Project Explorer`. Everything is fine and the subfolders are correctly shown now. Thanks.